# Insertar elemento al principio de un array. Java

Tags: java, array

¿Cómo puedo insertar un elemento (un entero por ejemplo) al principio de un array?
No puedo usar la clase ArrayList ni nada por el estilo, me podeis ayudar por favor? Gracias de antemano.

Esta es la cabecera del metodo

```
public void addFirst(int newElem);
```

Y aqui mi clase

```
public class ListArray{

private int size;
private int[] numeros;

public ListArray(int size){
    numeros = new int[size];
    for (int i=0;i<size;i++){
        numeros[i]=(int)(Math.random()*10+1);
    }
}
```

Esto es lo que tengo

```
public void addFirst(int newElem){
    int[] nuevo = new int[this.size+1];
    nuevo[0]=newElem;
    for (int i=1;i<nuevo.length;i++){
        nuevo[i]=numeros[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: el problema es que no sabes como hacer el metodo addFirst? probaste algo? cualquier cosa?

Comment: De paso, no solamente es suficiente con saber que hay que agregarlo al principio. Habria que aclarar que hacer si se "caen" elementos, y si el nuevo reemplaza o desplaza a los que estan

Comment: y cual es el problema con ese codigo? no copia el primero de la vieja lista?

Comment: Los desplaza, es decir,el primer indice es el que yo inserto, y los demas se desplazan una posicion a la derecha

Comment: Es que yo lo que quiero es hacerlo todo con el mismo array numeros, se podria?

Comment: es que si no se puede redimensionar, como podria imprimir en el main el nuevo array, si no puedo acceder a el, no?

Comment: puedes pasarme el enlace del chat que no logro acceder?

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72400/discussion-between-traxomax-and-gbianchi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Casi estas lograndolo. Solo te falto que al nuevo array, comienze a insertar los demas elementos despues del primer elemento ya insertado:

```
static int[] addFirst(int item, int[] array) {
        int[] newArray = new int[array.length + 1];

        newArray[0] = item;
        for(int i = 0;i<array.length;i++){
            // agregamos los demas elementos despues del indice 0
            newArray[i+1] = array[i];
        }

        return newArray;
    }
```

Comment: Me ha servido para darme cuenta del error, lo que pasa es que tengo que usar la misma cabecera que puse antes   public void

Comment: Le aclaras que esta funcion devuelve un nuevo array que podria usar para reemplazar el anterior (no quiero editar tu respuesta) y usarlo para futuras cosas que necesite? Me parece que su confusion viene por ahi...

Comment: ya se como usarlo, muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

La solución anterior era un poco más estilosa, pero también puedes hacerlo todo manuelmente (o nativamente) con el siguiente código:

```
int size =10;
        Integer[] list = new Integer[size];
        Integer[] copyList = new Integer[size+1];
        copyList[0] = 10; //nuevo valor
        for (int i = 1; i < copyList.length; i++) {
            copyList[i] = list[i-1];
        }
        list = copyList;
```

Comment: no he dado lo de Integer[] aun... pero gracias de todas formas

Comment: **Es recomendable no agregar varias respuestas**, edita la que realizaste. Revisar [answer]

Comment: Son dos soluciones diferentes amigo, igual gracias por el comentario.

Comment: Soluciones diferentes o actualizaciones, se agregan a la misma respuesta.